# Infinite loop and xmlhttprequests in multiple tabs

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, infinite-loop, browser-tab

*I have a `PHP` file with infinite loop `while(true){}`. The file is loaded with `Ajax request`.*

**If I have multiple tabs opened in the same browser, is it possible to reffer only to one request?**

*I mean, if I open 10 tabs the `ajax request` will open my php file 10 times and I will have 10 files performing infinite loop `while(true){}`, and this is not very good for my server.*

**Again : Is it possible? :)**

*Sorry for this question, but I can't find solution for it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem goes to identify the tab of the user. You can use a POST variable to do it.

Please refer to these questions:

- [detect current tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396947/detect-current-tab)
- [How to detect if user open two tabs for same session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574970/how-to-detect-if-user-open-two-tabs-for-same-session)